# How/where to save a double-entry table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, matrix, html5-canvas

I'm building a `javascript - html5` `canvas` side-scroller game. The terrain consists basically on a double-entry table like this one:

```
      -1   2   10  
-----------------
0     b    a    c
-----------------
2     a    b    a
-----------------
5     a    a    b
-----------------
```

(the columns and rows represent the position on the map and `a`, `b` and `c` would state what's on that space).

I don't know how to save this table so I can retrieve any range of it quickly later on. I can't think of any terminology that helps me search for the solution either, so any info and help tagging the question will be of help.

Comment: You want to save it where? JSON could be helpful.

Comment: `I don't know how to save this table` not understood to me...you can use array to save your matrix.

Comment: Would a two-dimensional array - an array of arrays - be sufficient?

Comment: @Liso22 : added some useful tags

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "double-entry"? Do you mean 2-dimensional? Regardless, unless we know a little more about what you're doing -- why do you want to save this table, who should have access to this table, and so on -- and you might want to start learning about arrays if you're going to work with multidimensional data.

Comment: @DavidPärsson I'm not sure, I dismissed using a two dimension array since I had negative values and probably would have to combine more than one. I know it's possible I just don't know if it's the most efficient way

Comment: @Ally sorry double-entry is common in spanish. It's two dimensiional, I need to save the whole matrix and then draw a little cuadrant depending on the moment.

Comment: if you are looking for a fast algorithm for the range search, than a tree structure and search could be fast too.

Comment: coincidentally hit enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON for saving such data:

```
var map = {
    '0': {
        '-1': 'b',
        '2': 'a',
        '10': 'c'
    },
    '2': {
        '-1': 'a',
        '2': 'b',
        '10': 'a'
    },
    '5': {
        '-1': 'a',
        '2': 'a',
        '10': 'b'
    }
};
```

And retrieve your data like that: `map['2']['-1']`.
You can also change it like that also `map['2']['-1'] = 'c'`.


Some function for easier manipulation of this object could be written by you if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON: JavaScript Object Notation. Fortunately, you can notate arrays with it too.

I don't know if you want to store the data like 'saving' - so that if the user leaves the page he can continue from the place he left  - or if you want to store the data as an internal representation of the map.

'saving':
You can use sessionStorage for that, but I believe that's an HTML5 feature (not sure). Anyway, here is the caniuse page for it: http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage.
Example:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("map", "{'-1': {0:b, 2:a, 5:a}, '2': {0:a, 2:b, 5:a}, '10':{0:c, 2:a, 5:b}}");
```

Then later retrieve it with:

```
var map = window.sessionStorage.getItem("map");
map = JSON.parse(map);
map[-1][0]; // Should be 'b'
```

The downside is that you can only store strings in sessionStorage, but see how I handled that using `JSON.parse()`. If you want to stringify an object you can use `JSON.stringify()`.

internal representation:

yabol beat me on that, but I was going to suggest the same:

```
var map = {'-1': {0:b, 2:a, 5:a}, '2': {0:a, 2:b, 5:a}, '10':{0:c, 2:a, 5:b}};
```

This time it is no string. It will be parsed to an object by the JS compiler (perhaps you already knew that).

Comment: You have to remember to use quotes with negative numbers in JSON object. Your code without quotes returns error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`